# Handle JSON Array posted from Ajax in Struts 1.3

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, struts

I build the JSON Object like this:

```
var key = //some calculated key
var key = //some calculated value

var list = {item: []};
list.item.push({
    "key"   : key,
    "value" : value
});
```

Then I send the array like this:

```
sendData = function() {
    $.ajax({
    url :'<html:rewrite action="/sendData"/>',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : {"list":list.item},
    success:function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error");    
    }
    }); 
}
```

How can I retrieve in my action the `JSONArray/JSONObject` and handle it?
I've tried this:

```
 public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        String list = request.getParameter("list"); //null, I supposed to find a string formatted like json
        return null;
}
```

Even GSON library is allowed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get significant improvement if you convert your object to string when sending it as parameter.

```
data : {list: JSON.stringify(list.item)}
```